# JQuery ajax call getting status code 0 "error"

Tags: jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest, jqxhr

I'm trying to call Petfinder.com to get a list of our pets.  The url is http://api.petfinder.com/shelter.getPets?key=xxxxx&id=CA1469&format=json

The url seems to return the JSON fine.  But when I try to make the call I'm getting "error" and status code 0.  I tried using jsonp which results in a status of 200 but a parse error.  If I change to xml I have the result of status 0 and "error".

```
 $.ajax({

         url: "http://api.petfinder.com/shelter.getPets?key=xxxx&id=CA1469&format=json",
         dataType: "json",
         type: "GET",
         success: function (data) {
             alert("hi");
         },
         error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
             if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
                 alert('Not connect.\n Verify Network.');
             } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
                 alert('Requested page not found. [404]');
             } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
                 alert('Internal Server Error [500].');
             } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
                 alert('Requested JSON parse failed.');
             } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
                 alert('Time out error.');
             } else if (exception === 'abort') {
                 alert('Ajax request aborted.');
             } else {
                 alert('Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText);
             }

         }
     });
```

Comment: Are you getting a `Same Origin` error in your console? Are you using IE? Cross-origin requests need to be sent either as JSONP (which require proper JSONP response) or with CORS enabled which requires the server to support CORS and the browser to support CORS. jQuery does not support CORS in IE < 10.

Comment: Trello's API client library has a good example of how they handle CORS support: https://trello.com/1/client.coffee

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ajax jqXHR.status==0 fix error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23802474/ajax-jqxhr-status-0-fix-error)

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure that when server sends you error response it also sends proper CORS headers along with it.

If it doesn't browser won't allow your JavaScript code to see any infomation comming from that domain, even status code.

Answer (score 1):

You're running into an <strike>XSS</strike> CORS issue. Best solution is to setup a proxy on your web server, and route the AJAX call through it.

Comment: As KevinB mentioned; I think you meant CORS, not XSS

Comment: I am using AWS Api Gateway for my appliction ... and getting this same problem ... can you suggest a preferred CORS policy such that this error is resolved. I am testing it ryte now using a simple ajax call which runs on 'onload' event of the body tag