# Ajax jqXHR.status==0 fix error

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

```
 $.ajax({
         url: urlString,
         dataType: "json",
         type: "GET",
         success: function (data) {
             alert(data);
         },
         error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
             if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
                 alert('Not connect.\n Verify Network.');
             } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
                 alert('Requested page not found. [404]');
             } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
                 alert('Internal Server Error [500].');
             } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
                 alert('Requested JSON parse failed.');
             } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
                 alert('Time out error.');
             } else if (exception === 'abort') {
                 alert('Ajax request aborted.');
             } else {
                 alert('Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText);
             }

         }
     });
```

This is my javascript file that im using to access some information from a server. The urlString is supplied and is correct. What I did was download the .json from the server that I was retrieving and accessed it locally on my computer. When I go to access the file from the server I keep getting jqXHR.status==0 error. I'm not sure how to fix that because I can't see anything wrong with my code.

Can someone point me in the right direction to fix my error?

Comment: Related, possible duplicate: [jquery ajax jqXHR.status is always 0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14313283/jquery-ajax-jqxhr-status-is-always-0).

Comment: no I've read that post and it is related but there is no action for the page. It runs when the document is ready.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that you get different status codes is that the file isn't fetched with the `http:` protocol but with the `file:` protocol. It's natural that different protocols have different status codes.

You simply need to have different behaviour depending on where you fetch the file from.

There is a [Mozilla bug report about this](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=331610), which is marked as invalid because this is considered to be the correct result.

Comment: @user3664250: Yes. You can fetch it from your own computer if you have a web server running on it and fetch the file through it.

Comment: See I thought of doing that through wamp and accessing the server online but it still gave me jqXHR.status==0

Comment: @user3664250: That's odd. Can you browse to the file through wamp?

Comment: What file are you talking about?
The one locally or on the server?

Comment: @user3664250: Locally.

Comment: Yes I can. I was able to get the page online and connect to the server but I still end up getting a jqXHR.status==0 error.

Comment: Would it be the fact that the url is for example "www.facebook.com" and not file.json?

Comment: The url should be something like `http://localhost/mysite/file.json`. Anyhow, the same origin policy may come into play here also. The error function is called with the parameters `(jqXHR, status, error)`, you should display the last two to see what the actual error is. The `jqXHR.status` value zero can be returns for several different errors.

Comment: error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) 
    {
   alert("xhr.status: " + xhr.status);
   alert("xhr.statusText: " + xhr.statusText);
   alert("xhr.readyState: " + xhr.readyState);
   alert("xhr.responseText: " + xhr.responseText);
   alert("textStatus: " + textStatus);
   alert("errorThrown: " + errorThrown);
  }
I changed my error function to this and I still get xhr.status=0, xhr.statusText=error, xhr.readyState=0, xhr.responseText=0, textStatus=error, and errorThrown=(blank). Even with those parameters the error function still didn't help uncover the problem.

Comment: @user3664250: From that I would say that it's not an actual HTTP request, that would give the HTTP response status back in the third parameter. Are you actually requesting the file through a web server?

Comment: Yes i'm requesting the url address through the web server.
The url is api.XXXX.co/?<parameters>

Comment: @user3664250: Unless you also fetch the page itself through a web server, you need to specify the protocol in the URL: `http://api.XXXX.co/?<parameters>`.

Comment: There's no page on the server just the url with the parameters that return a json information/document.

Answer (score 1):

**JQXHR Status: 0**

**Reason**: Request does not cancel when the Ajax function is called.

**Resolution**: Simply add `return false;` after calling the function, i.e 
`OnClientClick="AJAXMethod(); return false;"`