# jQuery .ajax() GET request not working from firefox. Works with Chrome

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am using a third party API to integrate some services into an HTML form I have.

To use the API you have to validate a hash value and timestamp for each request. After 30 minutes your hash and timestamp are no longer valid. To avoid an error from the API I decided to use JavaScript and PHP to dynamically set the value each time the form is submitted.

This is the PHP file I'm using to generate my hash and timestamp information.

```
 <?php
    if(isset($_REQUEST['action'])){
    switch($_REQUEST['action']){
    case 'getHash':
    //Assign your variables the necessary values.
    $base_url = "";//base_url value goes here. This is the location the request is sent to. 
    $account_id = "";//You must put your account_id here
    $api_accesskey = "";//You must put your api_accesskey here
    $success_url = "";//Your success URL goes here
    $decline_url = "";//your decline URL goes here.
    $timestamp = time();
    //The $hash_string concatenates your three required parameters that 
    //will be hashed. If you are using transparent redirect you must 
    //also add your success and decline URLs.
    $hash_string = $account_id.",".$api_accesskey.",".$timestamp.",".$success_url.",".$decline_url;
    //The $hash_value is the variable you will post.
    $hash_value = hash("sha256",$hash_string);
    $hash_data = array(
            'base_url' => $base_url,
            'account_id' => $account_id,
            'success_url' => $success_url,
            'decline_url' => $decline_url,
            'timestamp' => $timestamp,
            'hash' => $hash_value,
            );
    $jsonHash = json_encode(array('success'=> true,'data' => $hash_data), JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
    print_r ($jsonHash);
    break;
    }
    }
    ?>
```

This is the jQuery/JavaScript I am using to request the information for my HTML form and then subsequently submit that information to the third party API.

```
<script>
function getPaymentFormInformation(event) {
//this is the query string we send to hash.php to get our hash and   config information
var post_data = {action: "getHash"};
$.ajax({
  url: "hash.php",
  data: post_data,
  dataType: 'json',
  type: "GET",
  success: function(response ){
    //assigning the response to a variable.
    var json = response;
    //assigning our values for submitting our request.
    document.getElementById('account_id').value = json.data.account_id;
    document.getElementById('success_url').value = json.data.success_url;
    document.getElementById('decline_url').value = json.data.decline_url;
    document.getElementById('timestamp').value = json.data.timestamp;
    document.getElementById('hash').value = json.data.hash;
    document.getElementById('paymentForm').action = json.data.base_url;
    document.getElementById("paymentForm").submit();
  },
  error: function( error ){
// Log any error.
console.log( "ERROR:", "Request did not work." );
  }
})
return false;
}
</script>
```

This works perfectly on Chrome, but when I run it in firefox my AJAX request to hash.php fails every single time. I've searched and searched for someone having the same issue and I cannot come up with anything.

Any and all help will be appreciated.

UPDATE:

[image: This is what the firebug console is doing.]

EDIT: Updated my code snippet to reflect suggested changes in answers given. Still experiencing the same behavior in firefox.

UPDATE:

I have changed my error catching function to be more verbose from another example I found.

```
error: function(jqXHR, exception) {
        if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
            alert('Not connect.\n Verify Network.');
        } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
            alert('Requested page not found. [404]');
        } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
            alert('Internal Server Error [500].');
        } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
            alert('Requested JSON parse failed.');
        } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
            alert('Time out error.');
        } else if (exception === 'abort') {
            alert('Ajax request aborted.');
        } else {
            alert('Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText);
        }
      }
```

I am now getting:

**uncaught exception: out of memory**

Firebug output:

[image: Firebug]

I have updated my error handler to output to the console instead of throw alerts.

This line is being triggered when I send a request.

```
if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
console.log('Not connected.\n Verify Network.');
```

Comment: You *are* running this on a webserver, right? Any errors in the console?

Comment: shouldn't it be `post_data = {action: "getHash"}`? Or can we just send over a query string like that?

Comment: you forget to close script!!

Comment: Yeah. I've got it up on a webserver. I can't see any errors in my debugging console other than from this line. 

    `console.log( "ERROR:", "Request did not work." );`

I also checked the apache logs and nothing seems to be there (presumably because the request is failing to hash.php).

Comment: @satishrajak noted and fixed. I just missed it on the copy/paste. Thanks!

Comment: Check the Navigation tab as well. I'm curious if Firefox is not letting you make the call at all. Also curious if you are getting anything back that could help us figure out the problem.

Comment: @KJPrice I have update the post with information from firebug.

Comment: I love the message Firefox provides "ERROR: Request did not work.". So many helpful details there.

Comment: @KJPrice Also I have changed over to using `post_data = {action: "getHash"}` Still having the same issues in FF.

Comment: Again, curious, are you working on your local filesystem? Meaning, is the url something like "C\:..." or "\\file..."? Often times browsers require an actual domain to use XHR. Using localhost will get you around that issue though.

Comment: @KJPrice Yes, the error isn't helpful at all. But it's the same error I'm setting in the JavaScript. This tells me that the request is failing to hash.php for some reason :-/

Comment: @KJPrice No, this is running on a webserver that is separate from my local system.

Comment: Man, such an odd issue. What happens when you take the url provided from the Firefox screenshot and hit that url directly in another Firefox tab? I'm also curious if you have to provide "www." for rules mentioned in "PHP.ini" or ".htaccess".

Comment: Why are you setting a `contentType`? You are not even sending json to the server. You should remove that.

Comment: @KJPrice it works just fine when I hit it directly. I get the expected output and everything.

Comment: @jeroen I've ammended my request to `{action: "getHash"}` That would be considered JSON right?

Comment: @RyanCox No, jQuery will transform that to a normal encoded query string. Just remove the `contentType`. Note that you are not trying to process json on the server-side either, just normal request / GET variables.

Comment: You should not change the code in your question to reflect the code given in the answers as then the answers will stop making sense. You'd better put the modified code and results below the original version.

Comment: @jeroen noted. I'll make sure not to change it further. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After being given the information to add more robust error reporting I was able to pinpoint the issue.

My error script was failing at `if (jqXHR.status === 0)`. I was able to search on this status code and find a resolution.

> JQXHR Status:0 Reason: Request does not cancel when the ajax function
>   is called. Resolution: Simply add return false; after calling the
>   function, i.e OnClientClick="AJAXMethod(); return false;"
>
> Source: [Ajax jqXHR.status==0 fix error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23802474/ajax-jqxhr-status-0-fix-error) (second response)

Answer (score 4):

You are not sending json to the server, just a normal query string (both before and after the edit), nor are you processing json on the server side; you access your variables via the super-global `$_REQUEST`.

So you need to remove:

```
contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
```

As you are sending json back, you probably want this instead so that jQuery will parse the json string automatically for you:

```
dataType: 'json',
```

Now you don't have to parse the json manually in your success handler.

Comment: I have made these edits and the results are still the same in firefox.

Comment: @RyanCox Your screenshot is pretty much unreadable but there seem to be missing at least 2 tabs and the Response Headers. So it would seem that no request is made at all. Is that still the case with the modified code and do you get any warnings in the console in Chrome?

Comment: that is the case. I believe the request is not made at all in firefox. I receive no errors in chrome. Is there any other piece of firebug or dev tools in firefox that could be helpful? It isn't really giving me much information.

Comment: @RyanCox I think the `error()` function returns several parameters so you should start with dumping these on the console (like the `error` variable you have now).

Comment: Thank you, I will get started working with those parameters now and report back.

Comment: @RyanCox You should add that to the question when you have it, it will bump it question up in the Active Questions list and I will probably not be here anyway.

Comment: Thank you again for your suggestion regarding error handling. I learned a valuable lesson there. It definitely lead me to finding the answer to my issue.