# How to connect to external URL from mvc application

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

How can i call a external URL from MVC application.

I have an intranet application where i can have a search facilty to find the details by providing a student name. The search returns an html page with the details of the student .

My MVC web application has a page where i can provide a student name. My requirement is if i provide student name  a search should happen with the external URL (which i specified above) and want to populate my MVC view with details from the external URL .

For example if i give name swathi in my mvc application on change of the text box it should connect to the external URL (the search URL) and the remaining field need to populate from the result of the external URL (result is in html format). say my external URL returns Date of BIrth,address,emailid for my name "swathi"  ,so my mvc application with search for "Date of BIrth" and find the corresponding value and should populate my mvc razor view.

```
Edit: Tried as below
$("#Contactname").change(function () {
       $.ajax({
            url: 'http://XXXXX.intranet.group/Pages/PeopleResults.aspx?k=swath&exact=true',  
            type: 'GET',
            crossDomain: true,
            contentType: "text/html; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
               alert(1)
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
                if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
                    alert('1Not connect.\n Verify Network.');
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

here i am getting jqXHR.status = 0 error.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the **[`How to Ask`](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)** page for help clarifying this question

Comment: It would be better to using a web service to provide data to your system rather than parsing the HTML.  D0 you have permission to take information from the external URL.  If so then perhaps you can discuss with them a better way to access the data?

Comment: @Guru : Bear with me please, i have updated my question. This is the first question in my stack overflow and  have to learn alot to ask question

Comment: @james : I am having access to the URL. But the problem is i dnt know the owner of that application. So the only way is to traverse through html

Comment: Am sorry, but these kind of solutions will be ending up with a huge answer which is not the sole purpose in Stack Overflow. There are lot of answers out there.. You can try searching with `ajax`, `Web API` etc to start up with.. Basically you need to try first. In any point of code  you tried and stuck up facing problem, then we can easily guide you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write this method in the controller and debug and check the result variable if data is obtained..

```
 public string RequestforInformation(string Name)
        {

            string URL = "Your External URL HERE";
            HttpWebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(URL)
                       as HttpWebRequest;
            string result = null;
            using (HttpWebResponse resp = req.GetResponse()
                                          as HttpWebResponse)
            {
                StreamReader reader =
                    new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream());
                result = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
            return result;
        }
```

you should make use of AJAX calls and get the details from there and then fill up your rest of the page with those details ..

```
$("button").click(function(){// use onkeypress function(textbox)if button is not clicked
    $.ajax({url: "@Url.Action('RequestforInformation','Contoller')", success: function(result){
        $("#div1").html(result);
    }});
});
```

Comment: is it possible for you to provide a sample

Comment: Do you meants to save the content of URL to a text file.?

Comment: no ,,, that is just destination from where u get data ..
in your case url will be @Url.Action("Action","Contorller",new{id=1})

Comment: $("#Contactname").change(function () {
       alert(12);
        $.ajax({ url: "http://colleaguedirectory.intranet.group/Pages/PeopleResults.aspx?k=swathi&exact=true",type: 'GET',
            success: function (result) {
                alert(1);
                $("#div1").html(result);
            }
        });
});

Comment: I tried as above. but didnt get any response,

Comment: If contact name is text box you should be using the onkeypress or onkeyup functions instead of the .change function

Comment: it is giving error jqXHR.status= 0

Comment: are u bringing in a file ?instead of a html page >

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23802474/ajax-jqxhr-status-0-fix-error  chk this post

Comment: no i am actually bringing an html page only.

Comment: Content type is : text/html

Comment: stackoverflow.com/questions/23802474/… is about loading file

Comment: no that was abt error codes ... what exactly do u want to do >

Comment: I want to connect my mvc intranet application to a sharepoitn URL. . Requirement is when i write the staff name in my mvc view (on change event of text box)i need to connect to the sharepoint URL where i will get the details of the staff name entered like age, dob etc.Those details i need to show in the mvc view

Comment: Explained in detail in the question

Comment: Yes u have to make ajax call as shown in answer to the location from where you get the data of the staff ,
2) Then return the partial view back to the json method

Comment: i will have a look. I have edited the question with my approach. But here i am always getting jqXHR.status = 0.

Comment: oh ok ... you should use this ... check updated answer..

Comment: As mentioned in the answer // logic that gets the staff data  ..this is the actual logic which i needed. The staff data is not in the database of my mvc project. What i have is a sharepoint url (updated in my questen) which gives a html page. i want the logic to connect to the sharepoint url from my ,mvc intranet application . If i can connect to the url i can read the details like age , dob from the html page and can bind to my view

Comment: I have posted about getting the response from a URL please chk the edited answer , also i have removed the earlier action

Comment: I will give a try.

Comment: Make sure you hit the proper method where the web request and response is written

Comment: sure. looks like it is not hitting the ajax call. i will see whats happening. change event of my button worked. but the ajax call s not invoking

Comment: put a button and on click of that button call the method and try first , if this work then you can go for onblur or onkeyup functions

Comment: In fiddler it caught error "Illegal characters in path". i moved it to the view and is hitting now. when it executes the line "HttpWebResponse resp = req.GetResponse()  as HttpWebResponse" getting 401 unauthorized error.

Comment: Please check the url .. i think you should be providing the necessary credentials to access data from that url

Comment: I can access the URL through internet explorer. let me see whether i can give my windows credentials in the url

Comment: no i dont think its the windows credential .... the service you are requesting needs a valid user id and password

Comment: google abt sharepoint 401 error

Comment: is there any way to spedify use default credentials. let me update the flag to true

Comment: i cannot say that ? the url given to you should already contain the necessary details , if not you should contact your concerned higher authority regarding the access ..

Comment: I have added req.UseDefaultCredentials = true; and it worked.thanks Redevi. Now i need to traverse through the html

Comment: I am marking ir as answer as i am able to connect to the URL now.

Comment: Now i need to read the data from the particular div. Can you suggest me on how i can achieve

Comment: why do u need to do that ?

Comment: My uRL returns an html page. now as mentioned in the question i need the age dob email address etc of the staff and have to display in mvc view for the corresponding fields

Comment: See make a partial view with the contents u want to display ? and then return it ..
1) call the method to get data (Done)
2) send the data to the partial view(mvc) , and then return this file to the json 
Usuall it will be like 
return partialview("viewname",data); this is method where u make request to get the data , that method should return a partial which will contain the data u need

Comment: Bit confused..the action now returns a string of my html page.. let me do exactly what you said

Comment: yes pass that string to the view , and display the page ,

Instead of return result use
return redirectToaction("Partialviewname",result)

Answer (score 0):

In your View  :
1) create one div 
   
    
2)

$("button").click(function(){// use onkeypress function(textbox)if button is not clicked
    $.ajax({url: "URL", success: function(result){
        $("#div1").html(result);
    }});
});

Comment: tried this but no response